# Mouse listeners not working with innerHTML and images in a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery, mouselistener

Basically, for this snippet of code, I would like to get the picture to show when clicked on, as shown by my `onmousedown` function. But for some reason, when I click on the picture, it does not show the picture that I have called in my `server()` function. In addition to that, my counters (the buttons) do not work as they are supposed to (add and subtract).

```
<!-- HTML header and stylesheets -->

memory = 0;
hdd = 0;
usb = 0;
server = "";

function allInOne()
{
    document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = memory;
    document.getElementById("hdd").innerHTML = hdd;
    document.getElementById("usb").innerHTML = usb;
}

function server();
{
    div = document.getElementById("server");
    div.innerHTML = "<img src = 'server1.png' />";
}

<!-- omitted some HTML -->

    <span> Memory (GB) <span>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();memory++">+</button>
    <article id = "memory">0</article>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();memory--">-</button>
    <br />
    <span> HDD (GB) </span>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();hdd++">+</button>
    <article id = "hdd">0</article>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();hdd--">-</button>
    <br />
    <span> USB Ports </span>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();usb++">+</button>
    <article id = "usb">0</article>
    <button onmousedown="allInOne();usb--">-</button>
    <br />

    <span class = "button" onmousedown="mac"> Mac OS X </span>
    <span class = "button" onmousedown="linux"> Linux </span>
    <span class = "button" onmousedown="windows"> Windows </span>

    <br />

    <img src = "server1.png" onmouseover="server();" />
    <img src = "laptop.jpg" />
    <img src = "0009-03_lenovo_pc.jpg"/>

<!-- some more HTML below -->
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question has a better chance of being answered, if a) your title is more descriptive, b) your code comes *after* a brief introduction and/or question details - these are shown in the question lists - c) you try to keep the code to analyze as short as possible and d) you add search keywords to make the question show up in more queries.  I did this for you now, so e) please do not revert other user's edits, unless there is something wrong with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here you go.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
          memory = 0;
          hdd = 0;
          usb = 0;
          server = "";

          function allInOne()
          {
              document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = memory;
              document.getElementById("hdd").innerHTML = hdd;
              document.getElementById("usb").innerHTML = usb;
          }

          function server1()
          {
              var div_server = document.getElementById("server");
              div_server.innerHTML = "<img src = 'i_icon.gif' />";
          }

        </script>
```

1. removed a ; which was present after function `server()`
2. renamed the method to `server1()` since a variable is there named server.

change closing tag `<span>`  to `</span>`

moved all the ++ and -- operation before calling the methid allInOne().

changed all the event to onclick. I have used a different image from system.

and it working fine. please test now

Comment: And when you tried it a new picture showed up? Because some reason for me it doesn't work.

Comment: you have declared one variable with same name "server". Change the name it will work.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM!

Comment: you are welcome... the thing is-1 vote is looking weird in an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's better and more efficient to add event listeners from your javascript. Every `onmousedown`, `onclick` etc. triggers an `eval` action. There are 2 ways to add an event listener to a HTML element: `[element].on[action] = [some function]` or using the `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` method of a html element.

Have a look at [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rAabG/) to see if you can apply that to your code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Javascript </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css.css">
            <script type = "text/javascript">
            memory = 0;
            hdd = 0;
            usb = 0;
            server = "";

            function allInOne()
            {
            document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = memory;
            document.getElementById("hdd").innerHTML = hdd;
            document.getElementById("usb").innerHTML = usb;

            }

            function server()
            {
            div = document.getElementById("server");
            div.innerHTML = "<img src = 'server1.png' />";
            }
            function changeText(id)
            {
                if(id == 'mac')
                {
                txt = document.getElementById("mac");
                txt.innerHTML = "mac";
                }
                else if(id =='linux' )
                {
                txt = document.getElementById("linux");
                txt.innerHTML = "linux";
                }
                else
                {
                txt = document.getElementById("windows");
                txt.innerHTML = "windows";
                }
            }


        </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <span> Memory (GB) <span>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();memory++">+</button>
                <article id = "memory">0</article>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();memory--">-</button>
                <br />
        <span> HDD (GB) </span>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();hdd++">+</button>
                <article id = "hdd">0</article>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();hdd--">-</button>
                <br />
        <span> USB Ports </span>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();usb++">+</button>
                <article id = "usb">0</article>
            <button onmousedown="allInOne();usb--">-</button>
                <br />


        <span class = "button" onmousedown="changeText(this.id);" id="mac"> Mac OS X </span>
        <span class = "button" onmousedown="changeText(this.id);" id="linux"> Linux </span>
        <span class = "button" onmousedown="changeText(this.id);" id="windows"> Windows </span>

                <br />

        <img src = "server1.png" onmouseover="server();" />
        <img src = "laptop.jpg" />
        <img src = "0009-03_lenovo_pc.jpg"/>

                <br />

        <div id = "server"></div>





    </div>


</body>
</html>




You did one mistake while declaring the function with ; like the following
 function server();
{
}
```

Comment: Just copy/pasting a snippet of code does not a good answer make.  You could just say "there is a ; missing", without the full quote - it would be much easier to read.

Comment: weltraumpirat in down i mentioned just see there and i changed something i your code to work copy the code what i have posted and see...

Comment: That's the thing: **Explain** what you changed instead of just pasting the code. No one will read through that entire block.

Comment: It's you who does not understand.  I merely edited  the question, it's not my code. I stand by everything I said above: The purpose of this site is to create a question-and-answer type of knowledge base.  Your answer will not help anyone, unless you explain what you did and why.

Comment: SivA: Have a look at @KooiInc's answer above. This is what a good answer should be like: Short, precise, insightful, and *showing OP the way to solve a problem*, instead of merely *providing a fix for it*. Plus, the code example is linked from an external source, so it doesn't clutter up the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semicolon currently on the end of the line:

```
function server();
```

Regarding the buttons: you don't actually say what is wrong with your add/subtract button behaviour but I'm guessing the problem is that you update the display first via the `allInOne()` function and then increment or decrement after that.

Instead of saying:

```
onmousedown="allInOne();memory++"
```

Try:

```
onmousedown="memory++;allInOne();"
// or, unless you have a specific reason for using mousedown rather than click
onclick="memory++;allInOne();"
```

Comment: The semi colon part I fixed but that still didn't help. And thank you for your tip about onclick and switching the syntax.